# How to store the Job id in static variable in two different executions

Tags: trigger, queueable-apex

I am having the trigger code in account object in both delete and insert context variable.I want to change the operations in queuable in trigger handler.

```
If(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isInsert){

i need to abort the Job here//
}

if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isDelete){ 
Accounttriggerhandler.Accountdelete(trigger.old);
}
```

**My Handler accounttriggerhandler class:**

```
public static void Accountdelete(List<Account> Accrec){

 Set<id> accid= new Set<id>();
 for(account account:Accrec)
        {
            accid.add(account.id);
         }
    

for(contact con:[select Id, name,Owner.Name from Contact where  accountid in: accid]){
                 
         
                ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
                 ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
                 ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
                 ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        
                 messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
                 //Mention user here
                 mentionSegmentInput.id = con.OwnerId;
                 messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);
                 textSegmentInput.text = 'Account is deleted';
                 messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
        
                 feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
                 feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
                 feedItemInput.subjectId = con.id;
        
                 ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
                 batchInputs.add(batchInput);  
              }
            List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :proj1.OwnerId];
            
            
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            //Message.isRichTextFormattedBody = true;
            message.toAddresses = new String[] {users[0].Email};
            message.setCCAddresses('test@salesforce.com);
            message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
            message.setUseSignature(false);
            message.subject = 'Account Deletion';
            message.HtmlBody = 'Account is deleted';
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
           } 
         }         
   } 
   if(!System.Test.isRunningTest()) 
            ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchinputs);
          
}
```

**I need to make it as a Queuable trigger handler and i need to store the job id and return the job id in trigger for insertion?**

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a static variable to store the job Id:

```
public inherited sharing class Accounttriggerhandler {
  static Id asyncJobId;
```

And then, in your after delete trigger, queue a queueable:

```
public static void Accountdelete(List<Account> Accrec){
  asyncJobId = System.enqueueJob(new QueueablePerformActionOnAccountDelete(Accrec));
}
```

And then in your after insert trigger logic:

```
if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isInsert){
  Accounttriggerhandler.checkJobToAbort();
}
```

And in your trigger handler:

```
public static void checkJobToAbort() {
  if(asyncJobId != null) {
    System.abortJob(asyncJobId);
  }
}
```

All that's left is to move your original code to a queueable class:

```
public class QueueablePerformActionOnAccountDelete implements Queueable {
  Account[] Accrec;
  public QueueablePerformActionOnAccountDelete(Account[] records) {
    Accrec = records;
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Set<id> accid= new Set<id>();
    for(account account:Accrec) {
      accid.add(account.id);
    }
    // Rest of the original code you had in Accountdelete should be here
  }
}
```

Comment: Great work You are always legend @sfdcfox